# Coldfusion 11 Installation - invalid credentials

Tags: coldfusion, installation

I just installed ColdFusion 11 on a Windows 2008 server. After installation,  I got the message to proceed with configuration using the link

http://foo.com:80/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm

where foo.com is 127.0.0.1

However, it keeps rejecting the userid and password I provided during installation for administrator. 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this being ran via built in server or via IIS?

Comment: How can I get this information ?

Answer (score 1):

This blog entry should help you: [Troubleshooting ColdFusion Admin Login Issues](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/troubleshooting-coldfusion-admin-login-issue.).

You can also try the following quick workarounds:

- Try an alternate browser (issue primarily occurs with IE).
- Try alternative address

  - `http://127.0.0.1:port_no/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm` or
  - `http://localhost:port_no/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm` or
  - `http://ip:port_no/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm`.
- Try the `passwordreset.bat` and then try with the same ip or loopbak ip
  address.
- Enable internal/built port for ColdFusion and then try
  `http://localhost:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm`, where 8500 is
  the internal port for ColdFusion.

Note: Enabling internal/built port would require a ColdFusion Application Server restart.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually due to reasons posted here - https://forums.adobe.com/message/6502639#6502639

> The issue is happening because of mime type (.air) entry specified in the web.config of the webroot.
>
> Can you try the following steps:-
>
> 1. Navigate to the webroot of **your** site.
> 2. Take a backup of web.config and open it with text editor (notepad etc)
> 3. Comment the entry for mimeType extension of ".air" like *<!--<mimeMap fileExtension=".air"
>      mimeType="application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip"
>      />-->*
> 4. Save the file and restart IIS.
> 5. Launch CF Admin and try to login.
>
> Commenting out the .air type in site specific web.config file has resolved the issue.